# Import functions from a different directory where those files only contain that one function each

Tags: python, directory, structure

I currently have a directory structure like:

```
project/
  indicators/
    __init.py__ (contains __all__ = ['ATR', 'MACD'])
    ATR.py
    MACD.py
  strategies/
    strategy.py
```

in ATR.py and MACD.py I have a function like:

```
def ATR(dataframe, period):
  # do math
```

From strategy.py I can do:

```
from indicators.ATR import ATR

ATR(dataframe, period)
```

or

```
from indicators import *

ATR.ATR(dataframe, period)
```

but I would like to do something like

```
from indicators import ATR, MACD

ATR(dataframe, period)
MACD(dataframe, period)
```

What is the proper way to set up this structure? I think I need a way to specify some sort of "default" export in each of the indicators/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `__init__.py` add, before your `__all__` list:

```
from ATR import ATR
from MACD import MACD
```

This will affect the other imports you don't like, but I think you will be able to see that you can manage what exactly is a name you are exporting, to your likings, inside `__init__.py`.

Comment: This gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ATR'` in the `__init__.py` (but it's there).

Comment: That depends on your entry point and import paths. Add `__init__.py` (even empty ones) to all project subfolders and to the project folder. Then fix import paths to absolute `project.something.else` or relatives ones like `.something.else`. You have to have a fixed execution entry point location. If it changes it never works for some of the paths.

Comment: @atkayla Where are you starting execution now?

Comment: Thank you! I am executing from `strategies/strategy.py`. There I put `from indicators import ATR`. In `indicators/__init__.py` I had to change it from `from ATR import ATR` to `from indicators.ATR import ATR`, then it worked. Also turns out I didn't need the `__all__` for my use `from indicators import ATR, MACD`.

Comment: Be aware that you might in the end want to start excution from a `main.py` or a `__main__.py` under `project`. Be sure to then check again the relative paths. Absolute always work but have the downside of using the `project` prefix and you may want to change the project name later.